# What are the steps to implement Angular 2 in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: angular, sharepoint-2010

What are the steps to implement Angular 2 in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the Angular works in SharePoint 2010, please modify SharePoint master page, for the default master page in SharePoint 2010 (v4.master), the X-UA-Compatible or default mode will be set to IE=8. In order to use Angular, you will need to change it least to IE=9 (you can also use IE=Edge to get the latest versions of the browser)

In SharePoint 2010, I don't recommend you use Angular. We can use some jQuery Plugin to achieve your requirement. To get data, we can use JSOM, REST API(listdata.svc) and we can use [SPServices](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices)

Comment: It would be great if share any link to implement Angular 2 in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

```
AnularJs is famous for its two-way data binding. If you want to take this advantage, then you can go for AngularJs. Otherwise, you should use JSOM. Moreover, REST API in SharePoint 2010 is not that much rich. For business logic (Angular Service), you have to depend on JSOM. You have to choose Angular version based on your IE version. Check following references.

Notes on Using AngularJS in SharePoint 2010

Internet Explorer Compatibility of AngularJs

In SharePoint 2013, REST API is much more powerful. Thus, you can consider using it. Some useful links are given below:

CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API
SharePoint REST API and AngularJs for 2013, 2016 and Online
```